# Solr edismax relevancy sorting multiple fields

Tags: solr

I use the edismax query parser to handle user queries against our Solr 4.4 server.

Im getting correct query ,but require help with the prioritization.

For example if i give q=ideapad miix 310

1)It will get all the exact matched ,this is working fine .Now if the results

contains ideapad instead of full matched word it should be given least priority

2)prioritization of results in this order

**field8,keywords,product,marketing,description** .Also here ideapad will be

have least priority.

MY bq:

```
bq:text:"ideapad miix 310"^20000  OR (text:"miix"^12000 -text:ideapad^-20 -text:thinkpad^-20 -text:ideacentre^-20 -text:thinkcentre^-20 text:"310"^1000 -text:ideapad^-20 -text:thinkpad^-20 -text:ideacentre^-20 -text:thinkcentre^-20)
```

URL

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=ideapad+miix+310&defType=edismax&bq=text%3A%22ideapad+miix+310%22%5E20000++OR+(text%3A%22miix%22%5E12000+-text%3Aideapad%5E-20+-text%3Athinkpad%5E-20+-text%3Aideacentre%5E-20+-text%3Athinkcentre%5E-20+text%3A%22310%22%5E1000+-text%3Aideapad%5E-20+-text%3Athinkpad%5E-20+-text%3Aideacentre%5E-20+-text%3Athinkcentre%5E-20)
```

I use the catch all field "text" and boosted copied each fields(field8,keywords etc....)

```
<field name="field8" type="text_search" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <field name="description" type="text_search" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true"/> 
   <field name="keywords" type="commaDelimited" indexed="true" stored="true"  omitNorms="true"/> 

  <field name="product" type="commaDelimited" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true" omitPositions="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true"/>
    <field name="marketing" type="commaDelimited_s" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true" omitPositions="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true"/>
<copyField source="field8" dest="text"/> 
<copyField source="field8" dest="text"/>
```

My solrconfig for edismax i have boosted the fields

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">

     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str> 
       <int name="rows">10</int>

       <str name="defType">edismax</str>
       <str name="qf">
      text^100 field8^90 keywords^80 product^70 marketing^60 description^10
      </str>  
      <str name="pf">
      text^100 field8^90 keywords^80 product^70 marketing^60 description^10
      </str>  

     </lst>     
</requestHandler>
```

Comment: Any inputs please ??

Comment: multiple copying the same fields is required for edismax ?

Comment: Please put in your thoughts...